# InvalidConfigurationException: Identity pool isn't set up for SNS using AmazonCognitoSync service

Tags: android, push-notification, aws-sdk, android-notifications, aws-sdk-android

I have been trying to use **AWS SDKs** for Push Notifications. But I am getting errors. Tried to find a solution, but can't find much support for this.

**iOS & Web push notifications are working fine**

**What all is already setup & done:**

- AWS back-end & console setting in place.
- Identity Pool Id & other keys in place.
- ARN topic in place.

**Android side:**

- AWS SDK dependencies:

  ```
  implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.16.8'
  implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.23'
  implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.15.1'
  implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-ddb:2.2.0'
  implementation ('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.16.8') { transitive = true; }
  ```

**minSdkVersion 21**

**targetSdkVersion 29**

- Inside onCreate:

  ```
  CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                  getApplicationContext(),
                  "My Pool Id here", // Identity pool ID
                  Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
          );

  CognitoSyncManager client = new CognitoSyncManager(
                          LoginActivateActivity.this,
                          Regions.US_EAST_1,
                          credentialsProvider);

              String registrationId = "MY_FCM_DEVICE_TOKEN"; **Instead of GCM ID, I am passing my unique FCM device token here. I searched, & it seems that wherever GCM is required, it is being replaced by FCM.**
              try {
                  client.registerDevice("GCM", registrationId);
              } catch (RegistrationFailedException rfe) {
                  Log.e("TAG", "Failed to register device for silent sync", rfe);
              } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
                  Log.e("TAG", "An unknown error caused registration for silent sync to fail", ace);
              }

              Dataset trackedDataset = client.openOrCreateDataset("My Topic here");
              if (client.isDeviceRegistered()) {
                  try {
                      trackedDataset.subscribe();
                  } catch (SubscribeFailedException sfe) {
                      Log.e("TAG", "Failed to subscribe to datasets", sfe);
                  } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
                      Log.e("TAG", "An unknown error caused the subscription to fail", ace);
                  }
              }
  ```

Error I am getting on client.registerDevice("GCM", registrationId);

> Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.cognitosync.model.InvalidConfigurationException: Identity pool isn't set up for SNS (Service: AmazonCognitoSync; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidConfigurationException; Request ID: a858aaa2-**************************)

**Note:**

I tried using Amplify libraries, but even that didn't work. Also, at iOS & Web end they are using AWS SDK. So I am also bound to use the same. This is not even a device specific error.

All I need to do is setup my project to get push notifications. But I am stuck at the initial step. Not able to create an endpoint for Android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the solution to the issue, thanks to a friend who shared  this link:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/create-android-push-messaging-sns/

This Youtube video also helped a lot:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QSO3ghSUNk&list=WL&index=3

**Edited code**

```
private void registerWithSNS() {

        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "Your Identity Pool ID",
                Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
        );

        client = new AmazonSNSClient(credentialsProvider);

        String endpointArn = retrieveEndpointArn();
        String token = "Your FCM Registration ID generated for the device";

        boolean updateNeeded = false;
        boolean createNeeded = (null == endpointArn || "".equalsIgnoreCase(endpointArn));

        if (createNeeded) {
            // No platform endpoint ARN is stored; need to call createEndpoint.
            endpointArn = createEndpoint(token);
            createNeeded = false;
        }

        System.out.println("Retrieving platform endpoint data...");
        // Look up the platform endpoint and make sure the data in it is current, even if
        // it was just created.
        try {
            GetEndpointAttributesRequest geaReq =
                    new GetEndpointAttributesRequest()
                            .withEndpointArn(endpointArn);
            GetEndpointAttributesResult geaRes =
                    client.getEndpointAttributes(geaReq);

            updateNeeded = !geaRes.getAttributes().get("Token").equals(token)
                    || !geaRes.getAttributes().get("Enabled").equalsIgnoreCase("true");

        } catch (NotFoundException nfe) {
            // We had a stored ARN, but the platform endpoint associated with it
            // disappeared. Recreate it.
            createNeeded = true;
        } catch (AmazonClientException e) {
            createNeeded = true;
        }

        if (createNeeded) {
            createEndpoint(token);
        }

        System.out.println("updateNeeded = " + updateNeeded);

        if (updateNeeded) {
            // The platform endpoint is out of sync with the current data;
            // update the token and enable it.
            System.out.println("Updating platform endpoint " + endpointArn);
            Map attribs = new HashMap();
            attribs.put("Token", token);
            attribs.put("Enabled", "true");
            SetEndpointAttributesRequest saeReq =
                    new SetEndpointAttributesRequest()
                            .withEndpointArn(endpointArn)
                            .withAttributes(attribs);
            client.setEndpointAttributes(saeReq);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return never null
     * */
    private String createEndpoint(String token) {

        String endpointArn = null;
        try {
            System.out.println("Creating platform endpoint with token " + token);
            CreatePlatformEndpointRequest cpeReq =
                    new CreatePlatformEndpointRequest()
                            .withPlatformApplicationArn("Your Platform ARN. This you get from AWS Console. Unique for all devices for a platform.")
                            .withToken(token);
            CreatePlatformEndpointResult cpeRes = client
                    .createPlatformEndpoint(cpeReq);
            endpointArn = cpeRes.getEndpointArn();
        } catch (InvalidParameterException ipe) {
            String message = ipe.getErrorMessage();
            System.out.println("Exception message: " + message);
            Pattern p = Pattern
                    .compile(".*Endpoint (arn:aws:sns[^ ]+) already exists " +
                            "with the same [Tt]oken.*");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(message);
            if (m.matches()) {
                // The platform endpoint already exists for this token, but with
                // additional custom data that
                // createEndpoint doesn't want to overwrite. Just use the
                // existing platform endpoint.
                endpointArn = m.group(1);
            } else {
                // Rethrow the exception, the input is actually bad.
                throw ipe;
            }
        }
        storeEndpointArn(endpointArn);
        return endpointArn;
    }

    /**
     * @return the ARN the app was registered under previously, or null if no
     *         platform endpoint ARN is stored.
     */
    private String retrieveEndpointArn() {
        // Retrieve the platform endpoint ARN from permanent storage,
        // or return null if null is stored.
        return endpointArn;
    }

    /**
     * Stores the platform endpoint ARN in permanent storage for lookup next time.
     * */
    private void storeEndpointArn(String endpointArn) {
        // Write the platform endpoint ARN to permanent storage.
        UserSession.getSession(LoginActivateActivity.this).setARN(endpointArn); //Your platform endpoint ARN. This is unique for each device, but changes when 
    }
```

Once an endpoint is created for the device, you need to store the endpointArn & FCM registration ID to your DB on server-side. Rest of the code will be your FCM implementation code for receiving notifications.

**Hope this helps someone**